# Resources not loaded from assets catalog in XCode 14

Tags: ios, xcode

I have iOS project that we used to compile for a long time with Xcode versions earlier than 14, using the 'Legacy Build System.' However, since the release of Xcode 14, the 'Legacy Build System' has been removed, and we were automatically switched to the 'New Build System.' I've noticed that the new build system works differently with assets catalogs. We added resources such as fonts and images to the assets catalog, and the old build system would put all these resources in the root bundle directory. However, the new build system puts all resources into the Assets.car file.

When I run the command `xcrun --sdk iphoneos assetutil --info MyApp.app/Assets.car`, I can see that all the required resources are inside Assets.car. However, when I try to request them using code such as:

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MyFontName" size:14.0]
```

the font variable is null, which never happened when using the old build system. This issue is not limited to fonts, as I've also tried to load other types of resources and encountered similar failures.

I'm looking for a solution to this problem with minimal changes to the code. Can you help me?"